# Checking if input is a float and has exactly 2 numbers after the decimal point

Tags: python, validation

I'm working on a class project that requires me to obtain a float value from the user. This float value must have exactly two numbers after the decimal in order to be a valid input. This is what I have so far.

```
while True:
    try:
        cost = float(input("Enter the price: "))
        if cost % 1 == 0:
            print("Invalid input for price.")

        else:
            if cost > 0:
               return cost

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input for price.")
```

Comparing `cost % 1` to `0` rules out ints and floats ending in .00, but I'm not sure how I could restrict the accepted input to a float with exactly 2 numbers after the decimal (i.e. x.xx). Also I believe I would need to accept a float like 5.00 so my method isn't going to cut it. I've tried converting `cost` to a str and setting restrictions on the length, but that still leaves it open to mistakes. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check it before converting to float:

```
cost = input("Enter the price: ")
if len(cost.rsplit('.')[-1]) == 2:
   print('2 digits after decimal point')
```

Comment: Clever, I like that solution! I've only used split a few times, so I didn't even think to do it that way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...             x = float(raw_input('Enter the price: '))
...             y = str(x).split('.')
...             if len(y[-1]) != 2:
...                     raise ValueError
...     except ValueError:
...             print 'Please try again!'
...             pass
... 
Enter the price: hello
Please try again!
Enter the price: 5.6
Please try again!
Enter the price: 5.67
Enter the price: 7.65
Enter the price: 7
Please try again!
Enter the price:
```

It gets the input as a `float`, and if the user does not enter a numerical value, it raises a `ValueError` by default. If it doesn't, then we get the string value of the price using `str(x)` and assign it to `y`, which we split by the decimal place. Then we can check if the last value in the list (the `yx` in `$x.yz`) has a length that is not equal to 2. If so, raise a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so complicated?

```
cost = raw_input('Enter the price: ')
if len(cost[cost.rfind('.')+1:]) != 2:
    raise ValueError('Must have two numbers after decimal point')
try:
    cost = float(cost)
except ValueError:
    print('Please enter a valid number')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *raw_input()* instead of *input()*.   That is safer (no use of eval) and it returns the actual string the user entered.

Then check the string with a regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = raw_input('Enter a price: ')
Enter a price: 3.14
>>> if not re.match(r'[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}', s):
        print 'Not a valid price'

>>> price = float(s)
```